# How to plot vertical lines with label on axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question regarding plotting vertical lines rather than points w/ label in ggplot2. I cannot think of a way of doing so. Appreciate any or all help! Thanks!

```
X     Y 
A     500
B     600
C     700
D     800
```

I was hoping to obtain something like the below using ggplot2 in which it would label A at 500, B at 600, C at 700, and D at 800 automatically based on the dataset rather than manually using geom_vline. Potting using lines rather than point. Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: You might be after `geom_segment`.

Comment: Do you mean horizontal? The lines you show are vertical.

Comment: Can you please put this in context of a "real" (sample) plot? Perhaps use `mtcars` or similar to construct a simple plot (scatter is fine), then describe how you want your lines (horiz vs vert, labels in/outside of the plot region, etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean *vertical* (as per your image), rather than *horizontal* (as per your text), you can replicate your image using your data as per the following reprex:

```r
df <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Y = c(500L, 600L, 700L, 800L))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Y), linetype = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$Y, labels = df$X, limits = c(300, 1000)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face = 2, 
                                   margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(5, "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>